# PHP String Indexing 'error'

Tags: php, string

Without wanting to sollicate the obvious Q&A, I'm wondering if anybody knows why the following happens.

I have a string variable $string with the value '1011100001111'

Testing for a '1' or '0' at a certain position:

```
$string[00] => '1'  // correct
$string[01] => '0'  // correct
$string[07] => '0'  // correct
$string[08] => '1'  // should be '0'
$string[ 8] => '0'  // correct
```

It took me a while to find the error when using prefix zeroes, and obviously I got rid of them, but why is index 08 different from 8? Note that up to 07 it does work!

Comment: If I remember correctly, when you use `08`, it uses the hex value of that number, not the decimal value. So it's not looking where you think it is.

Comment: [***To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero).** To use hexadecimal notation precede the number with 0x. To use binary notation precede the number with 0b.*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, octal, not hex. Thanks for clearing that up. :-D

Comment: PHP7 gives a `Parse error: Invalid numeric literal in...` i.e. `08` is an invalid octal number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) regarding integers:

> To use octal notation, precede the number with a 0 (zero)

So `08` is not the integer 8 and therefore not returning the index you expect.  It's an invalid octal and resolves to 0.

Comment: But There is good news. In PHP7 it will generate a Parse Error

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Makes me wonder what the result is if I use 008. I will try and find out.

Answer (score 0):

If you precede the numbers with 0, they will be considered octal numbers. So from 00 to 07, they are equivalent to 0-7 decimal. But 08 does not exist in octal so it resolves to 0.